# The data in VS debugging Window and that in the Forms are different in one debugging process

Tags: c#, winforms

I am programming a WinForm project including a function that shows the CPU usage percentage.
This function uses the `Performance Counter`.
The same code in VB.NET works well.
The following code is registered to a timer's Tick event.

```
Dim cu As Integer = PfmcCounter.NextValue()
Label14.Text = cu.ToString & " %"
ProgressBar2.Value = cu
```

and the PfmcCounter is a PerformanceCounter instant defined as a field.

When I have rewritten the code to use it in C#, it worked correctly if I set a checkpoint in the end of the method.(I could prove this: the numbers appeared in the debugging window were always below 20)

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = 
           new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

private void UpdateInfo(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     //cpu usage

     int cpuUsage = (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();
     labelCPUUsage.Text = cpuUsage.ToString() + "%";
     progressBarProc.Value = cpuUsage;

     //memory usage

     float memoUsage = ramCounter.NextValue() / s.TotalMemory * 100;
     labelMemoryUsage.Text = memoUsage.ToString().Substring(0, 4) + "%";
     progressBarMemo.Value = (int)memoUsage;
}
//the method is registered to a timer's Tick event and the timer is started normally.
```

However, if I cancelled the point, the Form was constructed, object "labelCPUUsage.Text" were always 100 although sometimes changed to 0. You can see this value was set using a simple =.

The number was never correct anymore.
But the memory usage works fine.

I have no idea why the data in the debugging window is totally different from that in the Forms.I also have no idea why the same code works fine in VB.NET but wrongly in C#.